# tkinter table:adding data into new row and specify index

Tags: python, tkinter, indexing

Has anyone worked with tkinter table?
I have problem with adding data into new row. I have an entry field in which user enter object. Then in `def onButtonSents()` I check if this word is contained in `objects` array and enter this object into the first column of the table naming Object, in the second column I add positive sentiments of the object and so on. I want by clicking the button add new row and put in different columns of one row values of dictionary. Here what I have for now:

```
file sentiment_analysis.py:
    objects [] #an array of objects which user enters into entry field
    positiveSentiments = dict()  #dictionary with key - object and positive words which correspond to it
    negativeSentiments = dict()  #dictionary with key - object and negative words which correspond to it


    array_cols = ['Object', 'Positive sentiments', 'Negative sentiments'] 
    var = tktable.ArrayVar()

#below is initialization of my tkinter table

    import tktable
    array_cols = ['Object', 'Positive sentiments', 'Negative sentiments']
    var = tktable.ArrayVar()
    table = tktable.Table(frame,
        rows = 1,
        cols = 3,
        roworigin=0,
        colorigin=0,
        variable=var,)
    table.pack(side='bottom', fill='both')
    var.set(index='0,0', value = 'Object')
    table.tag_configure('active', )
    var.set(index='0,1', value = 'Positive Sentiments')
    var.set(index='0,2', value = 'Negative Sentiments')

#The method which puts data into the rows of table
    def onButtonSents():
        table.insert_rows(1)
        for i in range (1, 5):
            index1 = '%i,%i'  % (i, 0)
            table.activate(index1)
            for key in sentiment_analysis.positiveSentiments.keys():
                if key == entry.get():
                    var.set(index='active', value=entry.get())
            for i in range (1, 5):
                index2 = '%i,%i'  % (i, 1)
                table.activate(index2)
            for key in sentiment_analysis.positiveSentiments.keys():
                if key == entry.get():
                    var.set(index='active',   value=sentiment_analysis.positiveSentiments[key])
            for i in range (1, 5):
                index3 = '%i,%i'  % (i, 2)
                table.activate(index3)
            for key in sentiment_analysis.negativeSentiments.keys():
                if key == entry.get():
                    var.set(index='active', value=sentiment_analysis.negativeSentiments[key])
```

But the cells of table aren't correctly filled. First object if filled correctly but then all objects become the same like first I enter 'ubs' and when I enter the second 'wheat' the first also becomes 'wheat' and their sentiments are also changed.

Unfortunately I haven't found any suggestions for this problem in the Internet. I would be very grateful for any advice!

Comment: what "table" are you talking about? Tkinter doesn't have a table widget or data structure. At least, not one named "table". Also, you don't show how you do the binding, and your code seems buggy (you do `var.set(...)` but I see no definition of `var`, etc). I don't think there's enough information in your question to help you.

Comment: I have added the initialization of tkinter table and var.

Comment: Help others help you.  Give us more details.  Tktable is not part of the standard Python distro, so it would help if you gave more details as to which version you're running, where you got the python interface module for it (are you using the one from the Tktable demo folder)?

Comment: I am using 2.7 version of Tktable and while installing I was following the instructions on this link http://blog.clintecker.com/post/148453368/tktable-for-tkinter-and-python
I imported tktable and looked its methods here http://tkinter.unpy.net/wiki/TkTableWrapper

Answer (score 0):

Below I have included my rewrite of your code to work the way you intended.

This runs properly for me.

Let me know if it works for you.

Please Note: I am using Python 3.6, tkinter and tktable.

Before I show the code, I will give a brief explanation of the tktable syntax for setting data into a row.

Your code was on the right track, but there were some errors preventing it from working.

Your first error was to use "var.set" to set data to the tktable array variable.

Instead, you should have been using "table.set" to set data to the tktable "table" pathname variable.

Secondly, because you are setting data to a row, you can use the set 'row' option.

Thirdly, you do Not need to specify "index=" and "value=".

You can simply enter the index  and value, separated by commas.

If you have created variables for the index and value, you can use the variable names.

To set multiple values to multiple indexes on the same row,

you simply add more values, separated by commas.

You only need to specify the index of the first cell in this row.

For example:

You wrote:

var.set(index='active', value=entry.get())

This should be:

table.set('row', '1,0', entry.get(), 'Positive Sentiments', 'Negative Sentiments')

The above line presumes you want this 'row' to begin at cell index '1,0'.

The code you provided did not run for me.

Therefore, to get the code to run as intended, I have added a class structure.

If you have questions about classes and how to use them, most of these questions have already been answered in detail on Stack Overflow by Bryan Oakley and others.

The class structure I have added to your code is based on what I have learnt from Bryan Oakley via Stack Overflow.

Also, I made other changes as follows:

Amended your onButtonSents method, by changing the conditional statements, and correcting the "insert_rows" syntax,

so that the correct data is added to the next new line as you specified.

If you have any questions about this, please let me know.

Added some test sample data to the "objects" list and for the dictionaries: "positiveSentiments" and "negativeSentiments',

to demonstrate how the code works.

Since you have Not specified how you would like the code to behave when the user inputs an object that is Not on the list,

I have left this for you to do yourself.

Here is the revised code:

```
import tkinter as tk

import tktable

from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

from tkinter import *


class Control(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.controller = self

        self.shared_data = {
            "objects": tk.Variable(),
            "positiveSentiments": tk.Variable(),
            "negativeSentiments": tk.Variable(),
            "x": tk.IntVar(),
        }

        self.title('Title of Control Class')


        self.entry_frame = tk.Frame()

        self.entry_frame.pack(side=TOP)


        self.user_input = tk.StringVar()

        self.test_entry = tk.Entry(self.entry_frame, textvariable=self.user_input)

        self.test_entry.pack(side=LEFT)


        self.test_button = tk.Button(self.entry_frame, text='Button', command=self.onButtonSents)

        self.test_button.pack(side=RIGHT)


        self.table_frame = tk.Frame()

        self.table_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)


        self.array_cols = ['Object', 'Positive sentiments', 'Negative sentiments']

        self.var = tktable.ArrayVar()
        
        self.table = tktable.Table(self.table_frame,
            rows = 1,
            cols = 3,
            roworigin=0,
            colorigin=0,
            colwidth=20,
            variable=self.var,)
        
        self.table.pack(side='bottom', fill='both', expand=True)
        
        self.table.set('row', '0,0', 'Object','Positive Sentiments', 'Negative Sentiments')
        
        self.table.tag_configure('active', )

        
        self.shared_data["objects"] = ['object1', 'object2', 'object3', 'object4', 'object5', 'object6', 'object7'] #an array of objects which user enters into entry field

        self.shared_data["positiveSentiments"] = {'object1' : 'positive1', 'object2' : 'positive2', 'object3' : 'positive3', 'object4' : 'positive4', 'object5' : 'positive5', 'object6' : 'positive6', 'object7' : 'positive7' }  #dictionary with key - object and positive words which correspond to it

        self.shared_data["negativeSentiments"] = {'object1' : 'negative1', 'object2' : 'negative2', 'object3' : 'negative3', 'object4' : 'negative4', 'object5' : 'negative5', 'object6' : 'negative6', 'object7' : 'negative7'}  #dictionary with key - object and negative words which correspond to it



    #The method which puts data into the rows of table



    def onButtonSents(self, _event=None):
        #self.table.insert_rows(1)
        for o in self.shared_data["objects"]:
            if o == self.user_input.get():
                if o in self.shared_data["positiveSentiments"]:
                    if o in self.shared_data["negativeSentiments"]:
                        if self.shared_data["x"].get() is not None:
                            self.shared_data["x"].set(self.shared_data["x"].get() + 1)
                            self.index1 = '%i,%i'  % (self.shared_data["x"].get(), 0)
                            self.table.insert_rows(self.shared_data["x"].get() - 1, 1)

                            self.table.set('row', self.index1, self.user_input.get(), self.shared_data["positiveSentiments"].get(o), self.shared_data["negativeSentiments"].get(o))

                        else:                            
                            self.shared_data["x"].set(1)
                            self.index1 = '%i,%i'  % (self.shared_data["x"].get(), 0)
                            self.table.set('row', self.index1, self.user_input.get(), self.shared_data["positiveSentiments"].get(o), self.shared_data["negativeSentiments"].get(o))

                         


Control1 = Control()

Control1.mainloop()
```